# Energy absorbed by a system in isothermic process in which the phase changes from liquid to gas

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, phase

A system contains $x$ mole of material, with surface area $S$ is pressed by a mass $M_1$ (no fraction and no any other outer forces involves). Let $\Delta H_\mathrm{l\rightarrow g}$ be the transition enthalpy from liquid to gas. The system is position in $(T,P_1)$ such that the material phase is liquid for those temperature and pressure values ($T$ and $P_1$). Now instantaneously the mass $M_1$ is decreased to to an **unknown** value which we denote $M_2$ so the pressure decreases. In case that the temperature stays constant until the inner pressure is equal to the outer pressure $(T,P_2:=\frac{M_2g}{S})$ system gets to back to equilibrium, and the material phase in $(T,P_2)$ is gas, I wish to calculate how much energy was absorbed by the system till it gets to pressure equilibrium $(T,P_2)$.

In the question is says that the volume of the liquid can be neglected when compared to gas' volume. And that the volume of the water is independent of the pressure.

What I did so far:

The chemical equilibrium pressure (i.e the pressure in the phase transition point) can be calculated because the exercise gives the triple point $(T_\triangle , P_\triangle)$ so using the transition enthalpy constant and the constant $T$ of the process, one can calculate $(P_\mathrm{l\rightarrow g, eq},T)$ (using Clausius–Clapeyron relation). And by $PV=nRT$ one may calculate $V_\mathrm{eq} = \frac{nRT}{P}$ the volume in the chemical equilibrium point. By the unstruction $V_\mathrm{eq}$ is the total volume of the material (we neglect the liquid volume)

We know the starting inner pressure which is $\frac{M_1g}{S} \text{[Pa]} $ and by the given instruction the pressure doesn't change the liquid volume we learn that until the phase transition point, the volume of the system stays constant $V_\mathrm{eq}$ which we calculated above.

When the system gets to pressure equilibrium point $(T,P_2=\frac{M_2g}{S})$ we don't know the volume or $P_2$ because $P_2$ is unknown how every we not that its larger then $V_\mathrm{eq}$.

I'm pretty much stuck here, I don't see how to translate this information to evaluate the amount of energy absorbed. It seems to me that maybe one more piece of information is needed, but the exercise doesn't give one.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that you started with all saturated liquid?

Comment: I thinks so, if saturated means the whole material is in liquid phase @ChetMiller

Comment: I assumed this.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated by @Buck Thorn,the work done by the substance on its surroundings is $P_2(V_2-V_1)$.  So, from the first law, $$U_2-U_1=Q-P_2(V_2-V_1)$$Solving for Q then gives:
$$Q=(U_2+P_2V_2)-(U_1+P_1V_1)-(P_2-P_1)V_1=H_2-H_1-(P_2-P_1)V_1$$Here, $$H_2=H_1+(H^{sv}_1-H_1)+(H_2-H^{sv}_1)$$where $H_1$ is the enthalpy of saturated liquid in State 1, and $H_2$ is the enthalpy of the superheated vapor that exists in State 2 (i.e., at a pressure lower than the equilibrium vapor pressure at the constant temperature T).  For an ideal gas, the change in enthalpy at temperature T from the saturated vapor in State 1 to the superheated vapor in State 2 is zero.  So the previous equation reduces to $$H_2=H_1+(H^{sv}_1-H_1)=H_1+x\Delta h^{vap}$$where $\Delta h^{vap}$ is the heat of vaporization at temperature T.  Substitution of this into the equation for the heat added gives:
$$Q=x\Delta h^{vap}+(P_1-P_2)V_1$$where $V_1$ is the volume of the saturated liquid at T. The second term on the rhs will typically be negligible.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed that there was no headspace above the liquid so no vapor in equilibrium with the liquid at 1. This does not change that my answer had a flaw but I still wonder if it would make a difference in the case of your answer? Somehow I think I'm visualizing the problem the wrong way.

Comment: @Buck Thom Once the pressure is dropped, the volume starts increasing, and you start forming vapor.  This continues until there is no liquid left (assuming that enough heat is being added to maintain the temperature).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have some questions:  1. what does $H_{1}^{sv}$ means in the equation $H_2 = H_1 +(H_1^{sv} - H_1) + (H_2 - H_1^{sv})$  (I think maybe $H_1^{sv}$ is super vapor and $H_1 = U_1+P_1V_1$ as mentioned before) 2. What does the $x$ mean in $x\Delta h^{vap}$.  3. At the end one needs to know $P_2$ to calculate the heat, but I don't see how to calculate the values of $P_2$ without knowing the new mass $M_2$. @ChetMiller

Comment: $H_1^{sv}$ is the enthalpy of saturated vapor at temperature T.  x is the number of moles of substance, as was indicated in the problem statement.  With regard to item 3, you are correct.  I guess they are assuming that, if the 2nd term on the rhs is negligible, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I wonder to what extent the result is path-dependent? (I am still not sure what might be wrong with my answer, but it certainly isn't as elegant a derivation as yours, and a whole factor of RT off...)

Comment: @Buck Thorn You were given the (irreversible) path, and you handled it perfectly, flawlessly calculating the work done by the system on its surroundings. Where you went wrong was in the way you applied the first law of thermodynamics. All you needed to do was to set the heat added Q equal to the change in internal energy (a function of state, not path) plus the irreversible work done by the system on its surroundings (which, again, you determined correctly).

Comment: @BuckThorn If the process were carried out reversibly, by first adding heat to vaporize all the liquid at the (constant) initial pressure $P_1$ and then easing up on the pressure gradually to $P_2$ while adding further heat to hold the temperature constant, the second term on the right hand side would be $xRT\ln{(P_1/P_2)}$

Comment: Yes, you got the right answer afaik. Thank you for your comments, I was looking for a shortcut and got lost along the way. I'm not sure why the OP accepted my answer. I'm assuming that you could also add a term for the heat associated with taking the liquid from the initial to the saturation pressure (while remaining liquid).

Comment: I made the assumption that since it's an ideal gas and an isothermal process, for the expansion of the gas $q=-w=P_2 \Delta V$ as I wrote in my answer. I see however how you used computation of $\Delta H$ to arrive at an expression for q, which is the right way to do things (assuming you know w).

Comment: @BuckThorn If you think my answer is right and yours isn't, you should delete yours.  In getting the work, there was no need to assume ideal gas an isothermal process.  If the external pressure was P2 throughout the expansion, the work would always be P2(V2-V1), irrespective of whether the gas is ideal and/or isothermal.

Comment: @BuckThorn Anyway, with a phase change, the internal energy change is not zero even if the temperature is constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95152/discussion-between-chet-miller-and-buck-thorn).